# Is this Chrome Bug? How can I solve? : It skips some alert comments in the opener's Function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert, window.opener

I poped a popup window. And the popup called the opener's function which has some alerts.
But,Chrome skipped the previous alert and executed the last alert.

Is this a bug of Chrome Browser?

**main.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function popUp(){
        winobject = window.open("pop.html", "popName","left=100,top=100,toolbar=no,status=yes,menubar=no,width=200,height=200");
    }

    function fnCallBack(param) {
        alert("1. msg (" + param + ")");
        alert("2. msg (" + param + ")");
    }

    function alertN() {
  alert("1. alert");
  alert("2. alert");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" value="alertN" onclick="alertN();" onkeypress="alertN();" />
 <input type="button" value="popUp" onclick="popUp();" onkeypress="popUp();" />
</body>
</html>
```

**pop.html**

```html
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javaScript" ><!--
function pressOk(){
            opener.fnCallBack("From Pop");
      window.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="pressOk();" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I press "OK" button in popup window, Chrome just showed only "2. msg ...".

Answer (score 3):

This is because of Chrome's [dialog policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy):

> `alert()` dialogs do not activate their tab. If `alert()` is called from a background tab, the call returns immediately. The tab is marked with an indicator and the user will see the dialog when they switch to the tab.

So what is happening here is that when the first `alert()` is called, the main tab is in the background, so the call returns immediately instead of stopping the code execution. This causes the second `alert()` to be executed, but the page is still in the background, so that call returns immediately as well. The function then completes and `window.close()` is executed. The popup closes and focus returns to the main page. Finally, since the second `alert()` was the last one to execute, Chrome displays the second message.

Compare that behavior to Firefox, which does not immediately return from `alert()` calls on background pages -- you will see both messages, and the popup window will stay open until you click "OK" on the second one.

Comment: Thank you, Herohtar for your explanation. I solved this problem by implementing alert function with div instead of alert original function.